# How do I check if a char is an ASCII number or period?

Tags: validation, rust, numbers, character, ascii

I would like to check whether a single `char` is an ASCII number (`'1' - '9'`) or a period (`'.'`). What is the best way to do that in Rust? I know that `is_digit(10)` is for numbers but how do I do it for numbers or periods (`.`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One small catch of [`char::is_numeric`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_numeric) might be that it matches on more than ASCII `0..=9`, e.g:

```rust
'½'.is_numeric() == true
```

There's [`char::is_ascii_digit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_ascii_digit) if you only want to match on ASCII `0..=9`.

The latter is implemented with the `matches!` macro. You can also use the macro for your use case, e.g:

```rust
if matches!(c, '0'..='9' | '.') {
  // Character is ASCII digit '0' up to and including '9' or '.'
}
```

Comment: This is actually a very elegant solution, which I didn't think of.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`is_numeric`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_numeric) OR'd with an `'.'` equality check:

```rust
fn is_numeric_or_period(c: char) -> bool {
    char::is_numeric(c) || c == '.'
}
```

Note: [`is_numeric`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_numeric) matches all numeric unicode characters, and will behave identically to [`is_ascii_digit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_ascii_digit) for ASCII strings, but if you're working with unicode strings and only want to match on ASCII numeric characters then [refer to @Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66077779/2766908).

Comment: As @Jason's answer points out, this is broken for characters like `½`. It needs to be `is_ascii_digit` instead of `is_numeric`.

Comment: No, it's not broken. `1`, `2`, `3` being recognized as "numbers" is very specific to your locale. Characters like `১`, `૭`, `൯` are just as valid "numbers" as ``, `` or `1`.

Comment: @user2722968 In the context, if you are matching digits or dots, you're parsing decimal numbers.

Comment: @PeterHall, correct, this is what I'm doing in this senario